# How to Import .edf file in Mathematica?

Tags: import

My file is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dbjE4zWRS4zKr2lQk05wg-bjEyM5KT0I/view?usp=sharing

I was trying to import .edf file in Mathematica, but every time it showed error.
    Import["File.edf"];

And it showed,

"Import:: Cannot infer format of file".

Please if you know reply.

Comment: You try to import a website, not a file. Try again with a downloaded version/find out how to get the path to the file from drive.google.com.

Comment: hi, Gladaedi downloaded then try to import that file, after that I got an error massage.

Comment: Looks like the file is corrupted. `Import["https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=
1dbjE4zWRS4zKr2lQk05wg-bjEyM5KT0I", "EDF"]` gives the following error: ToExpression::sntxi: Incomplete expression; more input is needed . Import::fmterr: Cannot import data as EDF format.

Comment: Rohit you have download that file then try

Comment: @RonySaha Yes, Same error with `Import["~/Downloads/AgB_1p3m_detector__54pt3C_2m.edf", "EDF"]`